# Autocomplete React comenzar a partir de la tercera letra

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy trabjando con el componente Autocomplete de material-ui y el unico problema que se me ha presentado es que necesito que el autocomplete se genere a partir de la tercera letra ingresada en el input , estuve tratando de configurar el filterOptions pero no encuentro un parametro que me de esa funcion en el componente.

mi codigo :

```
const filterOptions = createFilterOptions({
   matchFrom: 'start',
  stringify: (option: FilmOptionType) => option.title,
});
export default function Filter() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="filter-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      filterOptions={filterOptions}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Custom filter" variant="outlined" />}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: De hecho no tiene un parámetro para lo que quieres, tienes que usar la propiedad `onUpdateInput` para decidir si se va a mostrar la lista de resultados, cambiando ahí el valor de otra propiedad: `open`

Answer (score 1):

Funcionando, puedes probarlo en el [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/7e7xi?file=/demo.js:1039-1291) de material-ui

```
/* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete, { createFilterOptions } from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

const filterOptions = createFilterOptions({
  matchFrom: 'start',
  stringify: (option) => option.title,
});

export default function Filter() {
  const [cInput, setCInput] = useState(""); //Valor input desde el State
  const onChangeInput = (text) => {
    console.log(text);
    setCInput(text);
  }
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="filter-demo"
      noOptionsText="Sin resultados"
      freeSolo={true} //Para que no muestre si no se cumple la condición
      options={cInput.length > 2 ? top100Films : []} //Condición
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      filterOptions={filterOptions}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} value={cInput} onChange={text => onChangeInput(text.target.value)} label="Custom filter" variant="outlined" />}
    />
  );
}
const top100Films = [
  { title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 },
  { title: 'The Godfather: Part II', year: 1974 },
  { title: 'The Dark Knight', year: 2008 },
  { title: '12 Angry Men', year: 1957 }
]
```

No copié todos los ítems del array para no alargarlo tanto.

Comment: Excelente Solución , muchas gracias .-